# Notepad++ Regex How to add a number at the end of specific lines?

Tags: regex, notepad++

Can anyone help me with a little problem?

I have a lot of lines and they all look like this: `sample_text="value"`. And I need to find all of those lines and add a zero to the end of every value.

For example, I need this:

```
sample_text="20"
sample_text="45"
```

to become this:

```
sample_text="200"
sample_text="450"
```

I tried looking for `([0-9]{2})` and replacing it with `\10` but it also replaces values for different lines and I cannot figure out how to filter it to replace the values that only come after `sample_text=` and leave everything else the same.

**Edit:** Never mind, I'm just an idiot. It never occurred to me that I can just search for `sample_text="([0-9]{2})` and replace it with `sample_text=\10`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can search for `"+\r\n` then replace it with `0"\r\n`

Comment: what if he has something like `sample_text="test"`?

Comment: I was assuming he only had numeric values in the file

Comment: I think he also has other values, since in the title he refers to "specific lines"

Comment: Yes, values are only numeric but I found an even easier solution that I have no idea how I missed, but thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: Why are you using `+` quantifier? You should use end of line `$` instead of `\r\n` that will not work with linux EOL (ie. `\n` alone).